# Column-normalized inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we define $A^{*}$ of positive definite $A=X'X$ using following two steps:

1. let $B=A^{-1}$
2. scale columns of $B$ to obtain a matrix with $1$'s on the diagonal

For the case of singular $A$, we could use a tiny amount of Tikhonov regularization: $A^*=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}(A+\epsilon I)^*$

Is there a name of this operation, or a way to compute it efficiently? Regularized inverse is efficient, but what to use for $\epsilon$?

Replacing regularized inverse with pseudo-inverse in step 1. gives a dramatically different result.

For instance, if we define $A=X'X$ with

$$X=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & -2 & 2 \\
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -2 & -2 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Then $(X'X)^{*}$ seems to be

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{7}{4} & -\frac{7}{8} \\
 2 & 1 & -\frac{7}{2} & -\frac{7}{4} \\
 -\frac{4}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{8}{7} & -\frac{4}{7} & 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Motivation: empirically this operation seems give a way to obtain least-squares fitted coefficients of an autoregressive model of x, $x\approx Bx$ with diagonal of $B$ restricted to be 0's:
$$B=I-(X'X)^*$$

Checks in [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1I0nrp1BXPoemgf2vwuAOK3FY9qVV54uK?usp=sharing)

**Edited with answer**

The formula for non-singular version

$$B=(X'X)^{-1} (\text{zero_off_diagonal}[(X'X)^{-1}])^{-1}$$

where "zero_off_diagonal" sets all off-diagonal entries to zero.

Formula for singular version

$$P=I-X^\dagger X\\
B=P(\text{zero_off_diagonal}(P))^{-1}$$

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forumn-column-normalized.nb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\e{\epsilon}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\left(#1\right)}
$Construct the orthoprojector $\LR{P^T=P=P^2}$ for the nullspace of $X$
$$\eqalign{
P &= {I-X^+X} \qiq XP=0 \qquad\qquad\quad \\
}$$
and use it to construct the function
$$\eqalign{
D &= \Diag{P} \qiq
\LR{X^TX}^* &= P D^{-1} \\
}$$
Calculating a pseudoinverse is more reliable than approximating a limit with an arbitrary $\e$.

Although there is a limit expression for the pseudoinverse,
it's numerically unstable
$$\eqalign{
X^+ = \lim_{\e\to 0}\LR{X^TX+\e I}^{-1}X^T \\\\
}$$

---

In terms of the motivating model, note that
$$\eqalign{
B \;=\; I-\LR{X^TX}^* \;=\; \LR{D-P} D^{-1} \\
}$$

### Update

Exact (rational) calculations for the pseudoinverse
and the orthoprojector yield
$$\eqalign{
X^+ &= \frac{1}{650}\m{
114 & -122 & 40 \\
-97 & 81 & 80 \\
-158 & -116 & 70 \\
9 & 93 & 140}
\\
P &= \frac{1}{325}\m{
49 & 98 & -28 & -56 \\
98 & 196 & -56 & -112 \\
-28 & -56 & 16 & 32 \\
-56 & -112 & 32 & 64
}
}$$
resulting in
$$\eqalign{
D^{-1} &= \m{
\frac{325}{49} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{325}{196} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{325}{16} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{325}{64}
}
\\
PD^{-1} &= \m{
1 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{7}{4} & -\frac{7}{8} \\
2 & 1 & -\frac{7}{2} & -\frac{7}{4} \\
-\frac{4}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
-\frac{8}{7} & -\frac{4}{7} & 2 & 1
}
}$$

Comment: using "pseudo-inverse" in formula above actually gives a dramatically different result, added details. I'm guessing pseudoinverse gives the limit A+eps, but what's needed is to take limit (A+eps)/diag(A+eps), these two "eps" don't allow you to factor out the limit

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I updated the answer with calculations using rational arithmetic. Even performing the calculation in IEEE double precision, the result is within $10^{-15}$ of the rational result.

Comment: thanks, I misunderstood your earlier reply, that indeed works!

Comment: BTW, one thing I noticed is that while the original approach is unstable when matrix is close to singular, this approach fails when matrix is close to non-singular. IE, for that example $X$, if you add a column of values close to 0, then result will be far from coefficients estimated by fitting models directly

Comment: Here's what I mean -- take a 4x4 data matrix of rank-3 with the last row all 0's. Orthoprojection method works fine. Now replace last row with tiny random values, orthoprojection method gives near-random results -- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1I0nrp1BXPoemgf2vwuAOK3FY9qVV54uK?usp=sharing#scrollTo=21vfH2rQBNdq

Comment: Yes, when $X$ is full rank then $P$ is the zero matrix (since there's no nullspace). In that case you should use your original method, i.e. $$\eqalign{ &B = (X^TX)^{-1} \;=\; X^+(X^+)^T \\ &D = {\rm Diag}(B^TB)^{1/2} \\ &(X^TX)^* = BD^{-1} \\ }$$

Comment: OK, so it seems this method works for overconstrained problems (but sqrt op has to moved inside "Diag"), while orthogonal projector is for underconstrained. In practice it may be hard to determine which regime you are in, because of numerical noise, Tikhonov regularized inverse seems like a practical solution there https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-column-normalized-summary.nb